# Fáry theorem proof: why is this triangulated graph two-connected?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I don't understand the first steps of the Lovász's proof to the Fáry theorem. In the first step Lovász proofs that the $G$ graph is two-connected.

> First we show that if $G$ is any planar graph we can introduce new edges to turn all faces into triangles without getting parallel edges. For let us draw new edges as long as we can without parallel ones. The graph $G$ has no cutpoints; for if $G = G_1 \cup G_2$ with $V(G_1 \cap G_2) = \{x\}$, then take a point $x_i$ of $G_i - x$ on the boundary of the face which meets both $G_1 - x$ and $G_2 - x$; $x_1,x_2$ could be connected by a further edge. So $G$ is two-connected.

Could somebody explain it to me with drawings?

Answer (score 1):

If your graph has a cut-vertex, then it looks something like

[image: it's a graph]

where $c$ is a cut-vertex. All that's being said is that if your graph looks like this, then it must not be fully triangulated because you could add an edge between $b$ and $e$. So a fully triangulated graph cannot have a cut-vertex and must be two-connected.

Comment: This diagram is a little bit confusing because $c$ and $e$ are both cut vertices. Might it be clearer to add an edge between $c$ and $h$, say?

Comment: @JohnGowers yeah, since $e$ is also a cut-vertex you could symmetrically add an edge between $c$ and $h$. I think the point is clear, though, that if you have a cut-vertex, your graph is not triangulated.